# How to make a jquery action on a dynamically generated DIV

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have my hidden element like this

```
<input type="hidden" id="<%=compid%>" value="<%=compid%>" class="noclass" />
```

Also there is a scriplet on the page

```
out.println("<div id=\""+compid+"\">"+outputjson+"</div>");
```

What is the jquery way to hide this dynamically generated div?

Comment: var DivId = $(this).find('div.noclass');         
$(DivId).hide(); I wrote something like this and it didnt work

Comment: Why not just put the jquery farther down on the jsp page? You've got access to compid in the JSP so you should be able to just use it as your jquery selector, i.e. `$('#%=compid%')`

Comment: Put your jquery code inside $(document).ready and what is 'this' in $(this).find

Answer (score 1):

You can either add a class to all div element you want to hide and then hide it using jquery `$('div.div-to-hide').hide()` OR according to your code you can get the id of div from hiddent element as follows

```
$('input.noclass').each(function(){
    var div_id = $(this).val();
    $('div#' + div_id).hide();
});
```

I assume that you have many such divs and have one hidden input field for each div with class 'noclass'.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $()document.ready(function() {
        $("#<%=compid%>").hide();
    });
</script>
```

Hope it works! Remember to write this in the JSP generated page.